# Nativescript textFieldDidEndEditing delegate on textfiels

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nativescript

```
UITextFieldDelegateImpl.prototype.textFieldDidEndEditing = function (textField) {
    var owner = this._owner.get();
    if (owner) {
        if (owner.updateTextTrigger === enums_1.UpdateTextTrigger.focusLost) {
            owner._onPropertyChangedFromNative(text_base_1.TextBase.textProperty, textField.text);
        }
        owner.dismissSoftInput();
        if (owner.formattedText) {
            owner.formattedText.createFormattedStringCore();
        }
    }
};
```

The above core method is invoked whenever the end of textfield typing, i tried with overwriting the method on my page by

```
TextField._delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing = function() {};
TextField.ios.delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing = function() {};
```

but it didn't workout.

Note : I am looking for an alternative solution to get the textfield end edit event(not a property change with observable).

Usage: The textfield value should be inbetween some range 5 to 50 if it is not in that range i have to show a popup and make the user to choose a value from list picker.

In the above case the property change workout eg) if user wants to enter 15 , first they will type 1 and after that they will type 5 , so each time checking wont help in the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you have mentioned that you would like to use a different way to handle the textField focus lost.

However, in NativeScirpt the best way to do that is to setup `updateTextTrigger` to `focusLost` and to handle TextField propertyChange. I am attaching sample code:

`xml`

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
       <TextField hint="Field 1" updateTextTrigger="focusLost" id="tx" />
       <TextField hint="Field 2"  />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

`typescript`

```
import { EventData, PropertyChangeData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';
import {Observable} from "data/observable";
import {TextField} from "ui/text-field";

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    /*
    This gets a reference this page's <Page> UI component. You can
    view the API reference of the Page to see what's available at
    https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html
    */
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    var textfield:TextField = <TextField>page.getViewById("tx");
    textfield.on("propertyChange", ((args: PropertyChangeData) => {
        var tField:TextField = <TextField>args.object;
        console.log(tField.text);
    }));
}
```

Regard to the topic, could you provide some more info for the need of an alternative way to handle textField focus lost, rather use observable property change.

Comment: First of all thank  you @Nikolay for the updateTextTrigger  , i was unaware of that method. I have updated the description why i am looking for propertychange.

Comment: @Nilyaz, `propertyChange` will be fired just on focus lost. In the callback method, you could check for the `TextField` text `length` and show the `ListPicker` if it is needed